# MySql Import strange behaviour

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a csv file that is delimited by tabs.

Here is my query

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/news.csv'
INTO TABLE news
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
(url, storyid, title, date, details, category, author);
```

What happens is only the first column is loaded, (url).

The rest shows `NULL`. I have tried lines terminated by `\n` as well. Same result.

Any advice?

```
Table structure for table `news`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
`url` varchar(62) DEFAULT NULL,
`storyid` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`date` date DEFAULT NULL,
`details` longtext,
`category` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`author` varchar(110) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Comment: what is the layout of your excel file? Is the first column followed by any empty columns?

Comment: Hi, I shared it here: http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=78862

Comment: Ah so everything is on a new line, what happends if you use '\r\n'?

Comment: Hi, Everything goes into the (url) column.

Comment: @Sliver2009, Same thing. I just noticed now when I increased the number of characters for the url column, everything goes on there. But \t is suppose to work.

Comment: Why are you using excel/csv for this in the first place? It are only lines of text seperated by an empty line.

So it makes sense that everything goes into the url column, since the csv only contains 1 column. Namely the full line of text

Comment: @Sliver2009, What? The CSV contains many columns. I posted a link to it.

Comment: The link contained a CSV file which only had 1 column. (That is what I saw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the exact format of your .csv file but for Windows .csv format I always use

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

also (again depending on the data) try

```
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
```

If you're unsure of the exact nature of the data sometimes it is better to view it in hexadecimal to see how the lines are really terminated. I use Hexedit - http://www.hexedit.com/

Hope this helps.
Dermot

Comment: Hi, You are right, it turned out it was really comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments you can use '/r/n' for a new line.

However your csv file contains only 1 column, namely a full line of text.
That is probably also why only the first table column is filled and the rest is null.

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/news.csv'
INTO TABLE news
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(url, storyid, title, date, details, category, author)
```

This worked.

Turned out that even though it looks tab separated, it is comma separated. Dermot was right that you need to view it in hexadecimal view to see how it is really deliminated.